# res.send() not working for two different callbacks

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am unable to get `res.send()` to work for all the callbacks, an idea I had was to move the `return res.send({ error, success });` to a callback placed above but then it doesn't do the potential error/success messages for below.

I tried doing it a different way where I used a function like `createUser()` that used a callback to return an error/success message but also wasn't able to get it to work. Is there anything that can point me to how I can make this work properly?

A friend suggested using await and async callbacks, but when searching it I wasn't too familiar to understand how it properly works.

```
app.post('/create', function(req, res) {

    // -- Default Variables
    let error       = "";
    let success     = "";
    let formData    = req.body.formData;

    if (formData.userName, formData.userPass, formData.userEmail) {
        console.log(formData);
        conn.query("SELECT COUNT(userId) AS rowCount FROM users WHERE userName = ?", [formData.userName], function(error, results, fields) {

            if (results[0].rowCount == 0) {
                conn.query("INSERT INTO users ( userName, userEmail, userPass ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )", [ formData.userName, formData.userEmail, formData.userPass ], function(error, results, fields) {

                    if (results.affectedRows >= 1)
                        success = "Your account has successfully been created!";
                    else
                        error = "Unexpected error occured, please try again!";
                });
            } else { error = "You already have an account!"; }
        });
    } else { 
        error = "Please make sure all fields are entered correctly!";
    }
    // -- Return
    return res.send({ error, success });
});
```

Comment: `conn.query` calls an async callback and `return res.send({ error, success });` returns immediately. The values changed in the asynchonous callback are in a closure, that executes only after `return res.send({ error, success });` already returned the value. So the only error that might show up is the only one in `else` branch.

Comment: `if (formData.userName, formData.userPass, formData.userEmail)` doesn't do what you think. It should be `if (formData.userName && formData.userPass && formData.userEmail)`

Comment: To summarize what @px1mp said, you need to put `res.send()` inside the callback function.

Comment: Didn’t realize that I had that if statement incorrectly. Surprised it still got past that. As for putting res.send in the callback, the issue I end up facing is the other callback doesn’t work for any error/success messages.

Comment: See [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) for why it got past that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conn.query` calls an async callback and `return res.send({ error, success });` returns immediately. The values changed in the asynchonous callback are in a closure, that executes only after `return res.send({ error, success });` already returned the value. So the only error that might show up is the only one in `else` branch.

Try rewriting it with promises:

```
app.post('/create', function x(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        let error       = "";
        let success     = "";
        let formData    = req.body.formData;
        if (formData.userName && formData.userPass && formData.userEmail) {
            console.log(formData);
            conn.query("SELECT COUNT(userId) AS rowCount FROM users WHERE userName = ?", [formData.userName], function(error, results, fields) {
                if (results[0].rowCount == 0) {
                    conn.query("INSERT INTO users ( userName, userEmail, userPass ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )", [ formData.userName, formData.userEmail, formData.userPass ], function(error, results, fields) {
                        if (results.affectedRows >= 1)
                            success = "Your account has successfully been created!";
                        else
                            error = "Unexpected error occured, please try again!";
                        resolve({ error, success });
                    });
                } else { 
                    error = "You already have an account!"; 
                    resolve({ error, success }); }
            });
        }
        else{
            error = "Please make sure all fields are entered correctly!";
            resolve({ error, success });
        }
    });
});
```

Even though I know that always *resolving* is not a clean way to use Promises. You should consider changing your API return proper errors with appropriate HTTP error codes to client.

Answer (score 1):

I can see multiple issues with your code:

1. It's actually working, BUT it's logically incorrect, returning your empty `error` and `success` variables immediately, without waiting for your queries to finish.
2. You have some conflict with your `error` variable, consider renaming to something that doesn't overlap with your outside declaration. While it does work, it gives you room for confusion.
3. Your `if` has incorrect conditions and logical operators.

Here's a quick fix, but not considering that this can be much much cleaner. Also some quick tips:

1. Return/Terminate early if possible.
2. Avoid very long lines to make your code much easier to read

```
app.post('/create', function(req, res) {

    // -- Default Variables
    let error       = "";
    let success     = "";
    const formData    = req.body.formData;

    const { 
        username,
        userPass,
        userEmail
    } = formData;


    // Avoid too much nested code, terminate/Return early if possible.
    if (!userName || !userPass || !userEmail) {
        error = "Please make sure all fields are entered correctly!";
        return res.send({ error, success });
    }

    conn.query("SELECT COUNT(userId) AS rowCount FROM users WHERE userName = ?", [userName], function(error, results, fields) {

        if (results[0].rowCount == 0) {
            const parameters = [ userName, userEmail, userPass ];
            // Avoid very long lines. It becomes harder to read (TIP: Consider using lint)
            conn.query("INSERT INTO users ( userName, userEmail, userPass ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )", parameters , function(error, results, fields) {

                if (results.affectedRows >= 1) {
                    success = "Your account has successfully been created!";
                } else {
                    error = "Unexpected error occurred, please try again!";
                }

                res.send({ error, success }); return;
            });
        } else { 
            error = "You already have an account!"; 
            res.send({ error, success }); return;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: The return value of the callback function isn't used for anything. Why are you returning the value of `res.send()`?

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I believe both callback results were used. **First callback result** was used to check whether the userName is still available, see `results[0].rowCount == 0`. **Second callback result** was used to check whether a row was inserted, see `results.affectedRows >= 1`. I think it was his personal preference to not return the results itself and simply return a customized return value. Hope this clarifies it. Thanks for asking! :)

Comment: Those are the parameters, not the return values. I'm saying you should just do `res.send(...)`, not `return res.send(...)`

Comment: I see what you mean now. It's a force of habit. I Iike to terminate my functions early, using `return`s. Your point makes sense, let me edit that for you. Nice catch and thanks! Updated your earlier comment. ;)

Comment: You can use `res.send(...); return;`. Then it's clear that you're just terminating the function early, not trying to return a specific value that will not be used.